# Insert into google map fusion table

Tags: google-maps

is it possible to use insert statement the way select is used in the query here :

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'address',
            from: '1iG4AeLNRyT5B2eGNcKELv7rmdbXmReM597C0-Mw',
            where: 'ridership > 5000'
          }
        });
```

Comment: No, FusionTablesLayer() does not accept INSERTs, it's made for displaying data, not for manipulation of data.  You must authenticate yourself before and then send a query using a POST-request https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#insertRow

Comment: Yes , I have seen this example as well https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#ImportingRowsIntoTables ; but could not make much of it . Can you suggest how to make such an insert in a scripting language PHP or Python. It will be helpful , thanks .

Comment: The first step is not how to insert, the first step is how to [**authenticate**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271623/authenticate-application-with-oauth-to-access-fusion-tables)